# ¿Como puedo pasar mayusculas a minusculas y viceversa en una misma cadena en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

necesito pasar las minúsculas a mayúsculas y las minúsculas a mayúsculas a minusculas en una tabla de una BBDD. Por ejemplo

dxItw9a4   -->  DXiTW9A4

¿Hay algún modo de hacerlo?

Comment: Con las funciones `lower` y `upper` aquí en la doc. oficila mas información https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción sería utilizar [`translate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html), la cual:

> A cualquier carácter de la `cadena` que coincida con un carácter en el conjunto `from` se reemplaza por el carácter correspondiente en el conjunto `to`. Si `from` es más largo que to, se eliminan las ocurrencias de los caracteres adicionales de `from`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT translate('dxItw9a4', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/39495/0)</kbd>